# VBA code To set Print Area, fit to 1x1 page and not set print area for certain tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to set the print area of certain sheets in a workbook.  I'm trying to set the print area so it fits each tab on one page and doesn't divide it into several pages.  Also could someone please help me with code to not set the print area on certain tabs based on the same cell value in each tab?

```
Sub PrintArea()

    Dim I As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For I = 1 To 6

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(I)

    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:Z24").Address

    With ws.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1

   End With
   Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: I was getting a syntax error in the `.VPageBreaks(1`) line. The problem was that instead of apostrophe there was another symbol at the start of teh comment of this line. Now this seems fine. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there. You can loop through the worksheets directly and not have to reference them with a counter.

This should set you up pretty nicely :)

```
Sub PrintArea()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Index

        Case Is = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 'only perform action on first 6 sheets

            If ws.Range("A25") = "Yes" Then 'adjust to desired range and indicator

                With ws.PageSetup
                    .PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:Z24").Address
                    .Orientation = xlLandscape
                    .FitToPagesWide = 1
                    .FitToPagesTall = 1
                End With

                'set print area to only 1 page
                With ws
                    .Activate 'need to activate sheet to view Page Break Preview
                    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview 'need to view Page Break Preview to drag page breaks
                    .VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1 `drag page over so it's just one page
                    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView 'set view back to normal
                End With

            End If

    End Select

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I had to add an End If after End With because I was getting an error.  It works but only if there is no page breaks in the range("A1:Z24"). Any idea of how to get it to work if there are page breaks in the range (I just want one page per selection)?  Also, what if I only want to do it for the first 6 tabs, how could I get it to stop?  Thanks

Comment: I am getting a subscript out of range code error in the .VPageBreaks(1) line

Comment: what does your page look like in page break preview when it hits that line? is it already only 1 page?

Answer (score 0):

One needs to set not just the .FitToPagesWide = 1 and .FitToPagesTall = 1 but also, .Zoom = false.  The code snippet should be:

```
Sub PrintArea()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Select Case ws.Index

        Case Is = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 'only perform action on first 6 sheets

            If ws.Range("A25") = "Yes" Then 'adjust to desired range and indicator

                With ws.PageSetup
                    .PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:Z24").Address
                    .Zoom = False
                    .Orientation = xlLandscape
                    .FitToPagesWide = 1
                    .FitToPagesTall = 1

                End With

                'set print area to only 1 page
                With ws
                    .Activate 'need to activate sheet to view Page Break Preview
                    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview 'need to view Page Break Preview to drag page breaks
                    .VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1 `drag page over so it's just one page
                    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView 'set view back to normal
                End With

            End If

    End Select

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this code, actually zoom seted to False changed the behavior. This can be called without activation of each sheet:

```
    Public Function SetPrintArea(rows As Integer, cols As Integer)
        Dim MySheet As Excel.Worksheet
        MySheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets(sheetname)

        MySheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = MySheet.Range(MySheet.Cells(1, 1), 
        MySheet.Cells(rows, cols)).Address

        MySheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
        MySheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
        MySheet.PageSetup.Orientation = 2 '2 is code for xlLandscape
        MySheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False

    End Function
```